# How to manually install chat module in Humhub

Tags: php, chat

I just installed humhub and downloaded the chat module from github. https://github.com/ychoucha/HUMHUB-module-chat
I gitcloned it to humhub/protected/modules. But, it does not show up in the modules section of administration login. How do I install this or other third part modules in Humhub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this link https://github.com/humhub/humhub/issues/165 on Sep 12, 2014, Luke said:

You can also install modules manually:

1. Download Module (e.g. mail)
2. Put it into protected/modules/mail
3. Enable it in Administration -> Modules

I've tried with the Tasks modules and it worked. Make sure you have the latest stable version of the code from the Humhub repository. You also must be able to download that directly from the Administration > Modules > Find Online

Answer (score 0):

The module no longer works since humhub v1.0.

According to the docs you need to add a config.php file.
https://www.humhub.org/docs/guide-dev-module.html

**config.php** (replaces autostart.php)

```
<?php

use humhub\modules\dashboard\widgets\Sidebar;

return [
    'id' => 'chat',
    'class' => 'humhub\modules\chat\ChatModule',
    'namespace' => 'humhub\modules\chat',
    'events' => [
    array(
        'class' => Sidebar::className(), 
        'event' => Sidebar::EVENT_INIT, 
        'callback' => array(
            'humhub\modules\chat\ChatModule',
            'onSidebarInit'
            )
        ),
    ],
];
```